# C function declaration syntax - why does this work?

Tags: c, syntax, rtos, keil

I have been going through some RTOS example code (a slightly old version of Keil RTX, if anyone's interested) and I came across some syntax I didn't understand:

```
void job1 (void) __task;
void job2 (void) __task;
```

This was giving errors (error:  #130: expected a "{"), so changed the example code to this:

```
void __task job1 (void);
void __task job2 (void);
```

And suddenly the file compiled. I had thought functions declarations were just return type, name, and arguments. What is __task? I haven't been able to find the definition of __task because the project isn't building the map file correctly and I suspect I might also be missing a file.

Comment: Maybe it's a macro? if it was defined `#define __task *` for instance, I think that would compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not C, it a Keil compiler extension to C.

`_task` keyword tells the compiler *not to add the function entry and exit code*.

Read your compiler documentation to get more information.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sase.com.ar/2012/files/2012/09/RLarmSteps.pdf

Description of the program:

1. We will create a simple three task program using RTX.
2. Task1 and Task2 will toggle two respective global variables.
3. The init task will be used to create task1 and task2 and then it will self delete and disappear.
4. Task1 and Task2 will run sequentially in Round Robin mode forever. Tasks are created as standard C functions.

The __Task keyword tells the compiler to not create an entry and exit code for the tasks. RTX will do this.

(google search: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=__task%20keyword%20c%20rtos)